# Exploit JSON values coming from a get mapping

Tags: javascript, spring, model-view-controller, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I trying to find in my database an order via a webservice integrated in the order controller like below :

```
@GetMapping("/view" )
@ResponseBody
public Optional<Ordre> view(String id) {

    return ordreRepository.findById(id) ;

}
```

Then display the details of the order in a modal by using a javascript code like below :

```js
$('.view').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var href2 = $(this).attr('href2');
  $.get(href2, function(ordre, status) {
    $('#Modalview #num_ord').val(ordre.num_ord);
    $('#Modalview #dte_ord').val(ordre.dte_ord);
    $('#Modalview #dir_ord').val(ordre.dir_ord);
    $('#Modalview #ref_ord').val(ordre.ref_ord);
    $('#Modalview #pap_ord').val(ordre.pap_ord);
    $('#Modalview #boss_ord').val(ordre.boss_ord);
    $('#Modalview #suj_ord').val(ordre.suj_ord);
  });

  $('#Modalview').modal();
});
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="Modalview" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 10px;">&times;</button>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="padding-bottom: 50px;">

        <form class="form-horizontal" id="formview">

          <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="num_ord" name="num_ord" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input class="form-control pull-right" type="date" id="dte_ord" name="dte_ord" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="dir_ord" name="dir_ord" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="ref_ord" name="ref_ord" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group pull-right">
            </div>
          </div>

          <br/>
          <br/>

          <div class="form-group " id="pap">

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-3">
              <select class="form-control" id="pap_ord">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br/>
          <div class="form-group" id="boss">

            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-push-1">
              <input class="form-control pull-right" type="text" id="boss_ord" name="boss_ord" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group" id="suj" style="padding-top: 10px;">

            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <textarea class="form-control pull-right" id="suj_ord" name="suj_ord"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer" style="margin-right: -15px;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Return Back</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <!--/modal-body-collapse -->

        <!--/modal-footer-collapse -->

      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

But nothing displayed in the modal i don't know and there is no error or crash in the console in my editor . any one can help me and thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Have a try like below and bind your form object using `th:field` or `th:value`

```
$('.view').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
             url: /*[[ @{'/view'} ]]*/,

              success: function(returnedData){
              $('#formview').html(returnedData)
                 $('#Modalview').modal('show'); 


                },    

                error: function(xhr, exception) {
                    console.log(xhr);


                    } 
        }); 


});
```

Comment: this is gives me a json response in the browser but not displayed in the modal

Comment: gives also this error in the console of the browser [ SyntaxError: expected expression, got ',' ] in the line where you indicate the URL empty .

Comment: here url is not empty. it is the way of writing url when you use thymeleaf. but inside script tag you have to mention it .like` this  <script th:inline="javascript">`

Comment: [ SyntaxError: expected expression, got ',' ]

Comment: It's saying what to do.

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: You must have a typo mistake. Identify that line debugging browser console and make it correct.

Comment: the console indicate the line of url

Comment: remove that `,` and run adding it again

Comment: no results it seems that i made an error in the construction of my controller view